# SQL - SELECT with double GROUP BY as two-dimensional array

Tags: mysql, sql, select, multidimensional-array, group-by

I have the following tables with the described relations:

**alpha_codes**

- id
- code
- description

**beta_codes**

- id
- code
- description

**entities**

- id
- quantity
- alpha_code_id

**beta_codes_entities**

- id
- entity_id
- beta_code_id

What I would like to ask is if I can SELECT the SUM of quantities GROUPed BY alpha_code and beta_code, resulting in the the following two-dimensional array:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|            |   betacode1   |   betacode2   |      ...      |   betacodeN   |
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| alphacode1 | SUM(quantity) | SUM(quantity) |      ...      | SUM(quantity) |
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| alphacode2 | SUM(quantity) | SUM(quantity) |      ...      | SUM(quantity) |
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|     ...    |      ...      |      ...      |      ...      | SUM(quantity) |
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| alphacodeN | SUM(quantity) | SUM(quantity) | SUM(quantity) | SUM(quantity) |
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

So far I have the following simple query, which although it returns all the required data, the result set format is different and requires manual reform to build the two-dimensional array shown in the above table.

```
SELECT 
    `alpha_codes`.`code` as alphacode,
    `beta_codes`.`code` as betacode,
    SUM(`entities`.`quantity`)
FROM
    `entities`
        INNER JOIN
    `alpha_codes` ON `alpha_codes`.`id` = `entities`.`alpha_code_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `beta_code_entity` ON `beta_code_entity`.`entity_id` = `entities`.`id`
        INNER JOIN
    `beta_codes` ON `beta_codes`.`id` = `beta_code_entity`.`beta_code_id`
GROUP BY `alpha_codes`.`id` , `beta_codes`.`id`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+------------+---------------+------------------------+
| alphacode  |    betacode   | SUM(entities.quantity) |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+
| alphacode1 | betacode1     | SUM(entities.quantity) |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+
| alphacode1 | betacode2     | SUM(entities.quantity) |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+
| alphacode2 | betacode1     | SUM(entities.quantity) |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+
|     ...    |      ...      |           ...          |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+
| alphacodeN | SUM(quantity) | SUM(quantity)          |
+------------+---------------+------------------------+
```

In case of a small fixed number of betacodes, I was thinking of using multiple CASE statements for each one of them. However the real-world scenario includes about 850 alphacodes, 1000 betacodes and over 500k entities, so I'm really worried about performance issues too...

Comment: Look into using a pivot query.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! However, is there a similar workaround for MySQL?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It seems that SqlFiddle throws an error about user access, so I cannot upload a live example atm @Strawberry.

Comment: That was the least important part of the linked answer (which is why it was in brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution below : 
The SQL Statement has to be dynamically generated. 
The list of sum phrases (the portion with .....) have to be generated by looping through betacode values. You could put the Case Statement into a function, while sending the two parameters to the function.

Since you are already in a situation where you have to build N columns, N not known priorly but only at runtime, building the SUM phrase also dynamically based on betacode's value shouldn't be much different/difficult.

```
    Select alphacode, 
    Sum(Case `beta_codes`.`id` When betacode1_value_goes_here Then quantity Else 0 End Case) as betacode1, 
    Sum(Case `beta_codes`.`id` When betacode2_value_goes_here Then quantity Else 0 End Case) as betacode2, 
    Sum(Case `beta_codes`.`id` When betacode3_value_goes_here Then quantity Else 0 End Case) as betacode3, 
 ..............
    From 
    FROM
        `entities`
            INNER JOIN
        `alpha_codes` ON `alpha_codes`.`id` = `entities`.`alpha_code_id`
            INNER JOIN
        `beta_code_entity` ON `beta_code_entity`.`entity_id` = `entities`.`id`
            INNER JOIN
        `beta_codes` ON `beta_codes`.`id` = `beta_code_entity`.`beta_code_id`
    GROUP BY `alpha_codes`.`id`
```

Another solution would be :

a. Create a temporary table that houses the output columns. If a single table would be too many columns, create more than one, like a table partitioning, you could join them later.

b. Loop through the records. Start either with entities table or with betacodes. Write Update statements inside the loop that will draw values from the query that you already posted. If you loop through betacode columns you will be updating one column at a time for all entities.

Comment: So there is no other way than using CASE statements for each betacode? How is this performance-wise?

Comment: That would depend on what you define as performance. How many records are we talking about here (rough range), whether it is a one-time back-end activity by the sys.admin, or a real-time activity by lay users ? But yes, it's bad performance generally, relative to the other simple queries.

Comment: The above example is fictional but lets assume I'm talking about 850 alpha_codes and about 1000 beta_codes in a database with 500k entities. The good thing is that this is a used as part of an annual report generated for the admin and not a real-time aggregate for the end-users.

Comment: The numbers are less, that is a good part too. In fact, for this kind of situation, you could: (a)  create a temporary table (s) with the necessary betacode columns (required in your output. (b) then populate them with a looped series of Update statements with quantity sums drawn from the query you have already posted. Running a few hundred SQL statements, with each impacting a single column or record at a time, takes hardly any time.

Comment: Currently it takes about 35secs to execute the above query on my local container. I'm afraid this is not viable even for a production environment with much better specs. I'll try to implement your latest advice about creating a temp table and see how this goes..

Comment: oh, I would think 35 secs is not too much for a one-time activity. Neways, updated the answer to mention the update statement strategy.

Comment: Its a dynamic annual report, so 35sec for a form post and a datatable response would be on the edge. Paginated results would also require this query to run on every interaction with the output datatable, so yes I'd like to keep this to the minimum. In any case, thanks for your suggestions!